# Find Active/Open Dialog Panels - Netbeans Platform

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

Is there are any specific way to get active/open Dialog panel, which were generated by the code segment `DialogDisplayer.getDefault().createDialog(panelDescriptor)`

I have found that `WindowManager.getDefault().getRegistry().getOpened()` will return all  `TopComponents` which are currently opened. Is there are any similar method which return open `Dialog` panels.

*Environment : `Java 8u05` `Netbenas 8.0`*

Comment: Can I ask why you want to achieve this? What do you want to do with the dialog?

Comment: @padde thank you for your interest. I have several Dialogs which are created from the `DialogDisplayer.getDefault().createDialog(panelDescriptor)` method. There will be a situation i need to close all opened dialogs. But i don't have any reference to open dialogs. So i am searching for a method which will return list/set of open dialogs on a given time. `WindowManager.getDefault().getRegistry().getOpened()` will do the exact same thing, but for the TopComponents

Comment: I am not aware of a way to get all opened dialogs. Do you open these dialogs all by yourself? Wouldn't it be possible to store all references to opened dialogs in a collection and iterare over these collection at the moment you want to close them all?

Comment: Storing references is impossible for me aswell, since Iam creating the dialogs from a Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution:
`WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().getOwnedWindows()` will return list of dialogs which are open under the main window.

```
for (Window window : WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().getOwnedWindows())
{
    // Close and dispose the dialog 
    window.setVisible(false);
    window.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to iterate over all Frames you created:

```
for(Frame frame : Frame.getFrames())
{
    /* Find your dialog here */
}
```

but working with

```
WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().getOwnedWindows()
```

is way cleaner in my opinion.